# Class 'App\Customer' not found (View: C:\AXIS\globaltec-vuepanel-master\resources\views\backend\customer\view-customer.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy intentando agregar un cliente a mi base de datos llenando un formulario y cuando lo agrego me tira el siguiente error. Estoy usando Laravel 7 y MySQL como base de datos, no sé si es de ayuda pero lo aclaro por las dudas.

```
'Class 'App\Customer' not found'
```

Esta es la migration: create_customers_table.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCustomersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('holding');
            $table->string('company')->nullable();
            $table->string('legal_entity')->nullable();              
            $table->string('email');                
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->string('state')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('postal')->nullable();
            $table->string('cuit');
            $table->string('website')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('1');
            $table->integer('id_parentCompany')->nullable();
            $table->integer('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->integer('updated_by')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Mi modelo Customer:

namespace App\Model;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['holding','company','legal_entity','mobile_no','email','country','state','city','address','postal'
    ,'cuit','website','status'];

        }
```

Y por ultimo el CustomerController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\Product;
use App\Model\Supplier;
use App\Model\Unit;
use App\Model\Category;
use App\Model\Purchase;
use App\Model\Invoice;
use App\Model\InvoiceDetail;
use App\Model\Payment;
use App\Model\PaymentDetail;
use App\Model\Customer;
use Auth;
use Session;
use DB;
use PDF;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function view(){ 
        $allData = Customer::all();
        return view('backend.customer.view-customer', compact('allData'));
    }

    public function add(){
        return view('backend.customer.add-customer');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->holding = $request->holding;
        /*$customer->name = $request->name;*/
        $customer->company = $request->company;
        $customer->legal_entity = $request->legal_entity;
        $customer->email = $request->email;
        $customer->country = $request->country;
        $customer->state = $request->state;
        $customer->city = $request->city;
        $customer->address = $request->address;
        $customer->postal = $request->postal;
        $customer->cuit = $request->cuit;
        $customer->website = $request->website;
        $customer->id_parentCompany = $request->id_parentCompany;
        $customer->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
        $customer->save();
        Session::flash('success');
        return redirect()->route('customers.view');
    }
```

No entiendo porque salta ese error si en todo momento está incluyendo al modelo de customer, en todos los archivos. Si alguien tiene alguna idea y me puede guiar se lo agradezco. Cabe aclarar que en mi base de datos el registro se guarda pero al momento de mostrarlo en la vista de customers donde estaría el listado, salta el error.

view-customer.blade.php:

```
@extends('backend.layouts.master')
@section('content')
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper bg-white">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
    
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Clientes</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Main row -->
        <div class="row">
          <!-- Left col -->
          <section class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Custom tabs (Charts with tabs)-->
            <div class="card" style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);">
              <div class="card-header">
                 <h3 class="font-weight-light text-white">Clientes
                     <a class="btn bg-white float-right btn-sm" href="{{ route('customers.add') }}"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle mr-2"></i> Agregar Cliente</a>
                 </h3>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.card-header -->
              <div class="card-body">
                <table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-responsive" style="width: 100%">
                    <thead style="font-size: 14px">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="display:none ">Codigo</th>
                            
                            <th>Holding</th>
                            <th>Empresa</th>
                            <th>Razon Social</th>
                            <th>Telefono</th>
                            <th>Email</th>                            
                            <th>Pais</th>
                            <th>Provincia/Estado</th>
                            <th>Ciudad</th>
                            <th>Direccion</th>
                            <th>CP</th>
                            <th>Cuit</th>
                            <th>Website</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($allData as $key => $customer)
                        <tr>
                            <td style="display: none;">{{$key+1}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->parent->holding }}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->company }}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->legal_entity }}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->mobile_no}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->email}}</td>                            
                            <td>{{$customer->country}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->state}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->city}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->address}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->postal }}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->cuit}}</td>
                            <td>{{$customer->website}}</td>
                            
                            
                            <td>
                              <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm bg-gradient-yellow"  href="{{ route('customers.detail', $customer->id) }}"><i
                                class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                                <a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm text-white" style="background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #070525ce 1%, rgb(1, 0, 5)100%);" href="{{ route('customers.edit', $customer->id) }}"><i
                                class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                <a title="Delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{{ route('customers.delete', $customer->id) }}"><i
                                    class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
              </div><!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
          </section>
          <!-- right col -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row (main row) -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->     
@endsection
```

Comment: Según el mensaje, el error está en una vista, no en el controlador

Comment: Eso pensaba pero ayer no tenía ningun tipo de problema, y lo unico que cambie en el codigo fue que agregue dos funciones en el modelo, que son las funciones parent y children. Despues no toque mas nada del código. @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Copia el archivo **view-customer.php** porque tal vez en algún punto de esa vista estas haciendo algo como `<h1> {{ App\Customer }} </h1>` o similar.

Comment: @j0se Ahí edite la pregunta y pegué la vista. Aunque yo no veo nada inusual puede ser que este siendo redundante en algo o faltando agregar algo a la  vista o alguna error de sintaxis.

Comment: Si sacas `$customer->parent->holding ` sigue el mismo problema?

Comment: Podes pegar todo el stacktrace del error, que va a dar mas información de donde se esta produciendo.

Comment: @MateoG98 veo que sos la misma persona que hizo otra pregunta con respecto a como armar la relacion para poder traer un customer que esta asociado a otro customer. en la respuesta a esa pregunta tanto en la funcion children() como parent() tenes seteado 'App\Customer' haciendo referencia al modelo, cuando el namespace para ese modelo tuyo es 'App\Model', por lo tanto deberias poner 'App\Model\Customer', creo que tu problema debe venir por ahi. EDIT: acabo de ver que te contestaron lo mismo sobre la otra pregunta, eso lo tenes corregido?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes el directorio "Model" dentro de App?

Laravel 7 no lo tiene por defecto, los modelos se crean directamente en el directorio "App".

```
use App\Customer;
```

La ruta App\Model\Customer existe a partir de Laravel 8

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [answer]